# Can I sort values alphanumerically in google sheet and ascend the rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet with room names, but they are formatted like (M355) and then the purpose of the room? I know how to sort values alphanumerically but you have to use a written formula. I need the cell next to the rooms to stay with the room number, so I can see the extra data that goes with it. The attached image shows what I mean.
[image]

I need the cell next to follow but it doesn't sort right. Has anyone experienced anything like this? I could manually copy and paste the 50 rooms but I ain't feeling that, I also would like it to be able to revert to what it is now too if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a formula for that. You can just select the first row with your headers (assuming you have such a row), and create a filter.

[image]

By doing this, every data in the sorted column cells will bring its full row togheter.

Comment: And then how do I sort alphanumerically?

Comment: That's basically what it's doing. I just used a short example, but you can see it sorts out any column you want alphabetically - or alphanumerically, for that matter, because it compares the full strings character by character, while not letting 'larger' numbers appear before 'smaller' ones, as described [in this post.](https://instr.iastate.libguides.com/c.php?g=49432&p=318510) You could check if one of those formulas help you as well, but a simple filter will do the job just fine.